# GAE ndb.query.filter() not working

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a Story model that inherits from ndb.Model, with an IntegerProperty wordCount. I'm trying to query Story objects that have a specific word count range, but the query seems to return the same results, regardless of the filter properties.

For this code:

```
q = Story.query()
q.filter(Story.wordCount > 900)
for s in q.fetch(5):
    print s.title / s.wordCount
```

I get this result:

> If only ... / 884 
>   Timed release / 953 
>   Grandfather paradox / 822  
>   Harnessing the brane-deer / 1618 
>  
>   Quantum erat demonstrandum / 908

Here's the story declaration:

```
class Story(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    wordCount = ndb.IntegerProperty('wc')
```

I would expect to only get stories that have 900 words exactly--or none. Inequalities and sorting are also broken. I tried deploying to GAE, and I'm seeing the same broken results.

Any ideas on what would be causing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NDB queries are immutable, and  when you call `q.filter(Story.wordCount > 900)` you're creating a new query, and not assigning it to anything. Re-assigning to your `q` variable should work for you:

```
q = Story.query()
q = q.filter(Story.wordCount > 900)
for s in q.fetch(5):
    print s.title / s.wordCount
```